# on click method is not being called when clicking

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working one of my first web app projects, and is a bit stuck on transitioning from my "home" state to "overview" state.

app.component.html:

```
<div ng-click="onTextClicked()" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <div class="home-page">
    <h1 class="time-banner">{{time}}</h1>
    <h2 class="home-page-menu-button">{{activateTitle}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.scss:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  activateTitle = 'Click anywhere to open screen';
  time;

  constructor(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
   }, 1000);
  }

  onTextClicked()
  {
    console.log("New state entered");
  }
}
```

When I press anywhere on the screen nothing happens?
I would have assumed the console.log would have a log message, but that does seem to be the case?

Why is it not able to call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ng-click` in Angular2+, is `click`

```html
<div (click)="onTextClicked()" style="cursor: pointer;">...
```

If you need to do something with the data event, you can pass it in the function as:

```html
<div (click)="onTextClicked($event)" style="cursor: pointer;">...
```

```js
onTextClicked($event) {
  console.log("The event clicked: ", $event);
}
```

Comment: You the best ;) 
I knew I was missing something obvious